# How to mount volumes with docker-compose on windows 10?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-10

I have multiple dev systems (win10 desktop, macbookpro, win10 laptop, linux production droplet). my docker-compose file has worked fine for my unix based environments, but the win10 systems won't setup the shared volumes regardless of my path structure).

```
volumes:
  certbot-etc:
  certbot-var:
  web-root:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: C:\Users\name\Source\project\data
      o: bind
  dhparam:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: C:\Users\name\Source\project\dhparam
      o: bind
```

Normally I use the paths:

```
/home/name/api/data
/home/name/api/dhparam
```

I have also tried `//c//Users//name//etc..`

I tried `set COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1` from command line and did a full restart of Docker along with container stop and starts. It still has the same issue.

The shared drives in Docker for Windows has been confirmed to be checked on C:, along with Reset Credentials as well.

Comment: confirmed that using a separate drive letter did not work either, ```d:``` since I have other drives available.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of things, starting from "docker-machine mount" till "sshfs-win". 
For me, the simplest and the fastest way was using the Shared Folders of the VirtualBox *(where is created your virtual Docker Machine at Windows 10)*. You could create one or use the default one already available.

[image]

And then, use this as a Path for your folder on the docker-compose.yaml file:

```
/c/Users/your-directory-name
```

Or... use a .env file at the same folder where is your docker-compose.yaml, set the variable on it:

```
MYSQL_VOLUME_PATH=/c/your-directory-name
```

And on your docker-compose.yaml file, do like this:

```
volumes:
  mysql-db-volume:
  driver: local
  driver_opts:
     type: none
     device: ${MYSQL_VOLUME_PATH}
     o: bind
```

***Be aware***: *I am not saying that in a production environment you should go like that - I am describing a local development environment*